# Cobertura integration with tomcat

Tags: testing, tomcat, tomcat7, cobertura

I am trying to generate a test report using `cobertura`. I deployed my instrumented jars in tomcat and got a test report using the `cobertura.ser` that is created in `Tomcat_HOME/bin` .
The report only shows Line Coverage details. Branch Coverage is NA.

The reason might be that `cobertura.ser` inside `Tomcat_HOME/bin` doesn't get `cobertura instrument target` details.
So I tried to put the `cobertura instrument target` details in `cobertura.ser` inside  `Tomcat_HOME/bin`. This resulted in both Line and Branch coverage as NA.

Any idea what is going wrong? How to provide instrument details to `cobertura.ser` inside tomcat.
OR
How to point tomcat to a different `cobertura.ser` from which is formed in its bin folder. (Tried forming a `cobertura.ser` outside and copying it to bin. Still NA)

Answer (score 0):

The `cobertura.ser` is **created** by the instrumented files, it does not need nor accept any extra configurations. You should delete it before any new test.

Maybe you forgot to add/reference the sources when creating the report, this could result in an incomplete report.